# CSS3 Transitions with Queue

Tags: animation, css, queue

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9Wrz/1/) which you can see has a container having list of box elements. I want box elements to move from the bottom to the top line by line. Each line is 60px in height.

Now the problem is the boxes are added to the container with the height difference of 60px each box has speed set to 100s. The top most box moves faster than the last most box because they have same speed but different distances. How can I apply a queue like behaviour here assuming I want 100% CSS3 animations?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem with some basic Maths. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/youmere/vG2Rv/2/) if anyone need it.